# Call Flow from Batch sequentially Mule ESB

Tags: mule, batch-processing, mule-component

I create one batch flow. From one batch flow i am calling another batch and from 2nd batch i am calling simple 3rd flow.

I am getting problem in this scenario All are not working sequentially
I need all flows should work sequentially manner

For example I have 5 records are comming in batch and in 2nd batch 10 records are comming and from 2nd batch i am calling 3rd flow which is simple flow

Problem is 2nd batch is not waiting to finish 3rd flow execution,it continuously executed till 10 records,

I need first 3rd flow exection should be complete then and only then 2 records should be come

How can I solve this scenario

Please help me

Comment: It is a lot faster and easier for us to find and solve a problem when we can see the code.

Comment: I believe this is not actually related to [tag:batch-file], so, in case, please read the tag info and correct your post accordingly...

Answer (score 1):

According to Mulesoft Documentation

Batch Processing at a Glance
 https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/batch-processing

> A batch job is a top-level element in Mule which exists outside all
>   Mule flows. Batch jobs split large messages into records which Mule
>   processes asynchronously in a batch job; just as flows process
>   messages, batch jobs process records.

So the answer is that you are not able to run batch synchronously. After the input stage, mule will do a load&dispatch and transform the collection into a queue of individuals recordes that are processed asynchronously.

Any reason why you are using batch instead of normal Flow ???

Comment: Thanks for reply. If I use flow then if in middle my flow crash then it won't take next record, for example if my flow crash in 5th message then it didn't process further , it didn't take 6th record, can you help me?

Comment: You can send the message from Flow A to Flow B using VM connector instead of flow reference having a VM requester in flow A and a VM listener in Flow B.  Using this scenario you will:

A) increase the perfomance as you will work async
B) have the control for each of the elements as they will work in different threads ( async )